# Jquery/JS: Display select box through style display(none, block)

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am trying to display(block,none) select boxes(in this example only one select box) through a jquery command. But I am getting no results. I have this working with a hidden attribute but I need this work with a display(block, none).

**Non-working JS/JQUERY with display(none,block)**

```
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {
            obj.nextAll('.update').attr({'disabled': true, 'none':true}).html('<option value="">----</option>');
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('includes/update.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled none');
                } else {
                obj.nextAll('.update').attr({'disabled': true, 'none':true}).html('<option value="">----</option>');
                }
            });
        }   
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use attributes for hidding elements!!!

**jQuery:**

```
$('...').hide();
$('...').show();
```

**CSS:**

```
$('...').addClass('hidden');
$('...').removeClass('hidden');
```

**Vanilla javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('id').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('id').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks! I +1 your answer. Before I can accept can you help me plug this into my example.